# When clicking back button of browser, the page doesn't load automatically by applying the new URL

Tags: javascript, browser

Some background info:

for example, I load page with url1
then I used `window.history.pushState()` to modify URL to be URL2

I then click the "back" button, I noticed that the address line changes the URL to be URL1
but the page doesn't load to reflect the contents.

What is the trick here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for the window's `popstate` event like this:

```
addEventListener('popstate', function() {

    // code to be executed when back button is clicked

}, false);
```

Comment: so there is no automatic way to do this? even if the browser already has the right URL? It should be the native behavior of the "back" button, isn't it? Or, you mean, because I used pushstate, the default behavior of "back" button is changed? Thanks!

Comment: The traditional behaviour of the back button is to traverse to the previous page in history, but the use of the history API essentially overrides this with your own custom logic. The browser can't possibly know how to correctly reverse whatever you've done when you push state, so you'll have to handle the backwards case yourself.